# HTML Canvas - too many rectangles break page

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

My page breaks (chrome oops page) when I try to draw a large number (+5000) of rectangles on my canvas using:

**rectangle**:

```
ctx.rect(x,y,options.missSize,options.missSize);
ctx.stroke();
```

However, my page does not break if I draw the same number of circles, triangles or X's using any of the following:

**circle**:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x,y,options.missSize/2,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
```

**X**:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x - options.missSize/2, y - options.missSize/2);
ctx.lineTo(x + options.missSize/2, y + options.missSize/2);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.moveTo(x + options.missSize/2, y - options.missSize/2);
ctx.lineTo(x - options.missSize/2, y + options.missSize/2);
ctx.stroke();
```

**triangle**:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x, y);
ctx.lineTo(x+(options.missSize/2), y+options.missSize);
ctx.lineTo(x-(options.missSize/2), y+options.missSize);
ctx.lineTo(x, y);
ctx.stroke();
```

Why would `rect` cause my page to crash, when none of the other draw functions have any issues?

Comment: Are you also beginning a new path with every rectangle? Otherwose stroke will have more and more paths to cover, unlike the cases where you use beginPath every time.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: @doldt good eye! sure enough I forgot to add a `beginPath()` in that block of code, thanks! Post as answer and I'll gladly accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm posting my comment as an answer, as it seems to have proved a solution:*

Note how your circle and triangle examples start with `beginPath`, while your rect example does not!

[Here's the MDN docs on canvas' 2D rendering context.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) Note that `.rect()` creates a new path, while `.stroke` strokes *every path*:

> **CanvasRenderingContext2D.stroke()**: Strokes the subpaths with the current stroke style.

In your example you've been creating a new path for every new rectangle, and issuing a new stroke command after each, meaning your `stroke` command had more and more subpaths to stroke every iteration, hence the performance hit.